# mysql select on duplicate field_value update another field in result

Tags: mysql, transactions, duplicates

I got a db table that store transactions with these fields

> | s_no | txn_id | item_code | qty | log_date |

I need to fetch all the transactions of a single day with only items with their quantities.

The table contains multiple entries for same item and in result set I get same item repeated with different transactions.

I need the query that sum up the quantity for the same item.

Here is the sample data

> | s_no | txn_id | item_code | qty | log_date |
>   | 1    | pos-1  | mobile    | 2   | 09/12/14 |
>   | 2    | pos-1  | TV        | 4   | 09/12/14 |
>   | 3    | pos-1  | tablet    | 1   | 09/12/14 |
>   | 4    | pos-2  | TV        | 5   | 09/12/14 |
>   | 5    | pos-2  | tablet    | 2   | 09/12/14 |
>   | 6    | pos-3  | tablet    | 4   | 10/12/14 |

when queried for date 09/12/14 it should return

> |item_code | qty |
>   |mobile    | 2   |
>   |TV        | 9   |
>   |tablet    | 3   |

What should be the query for this result set.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what have you done so far? have you tried count function?

Comment: i am still not able to see, what have you done so far. Kindly help.

Comment: The query below in answer worked. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic mysql **[`group by aggregate`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html)** function

You need to use `sum` and then `group by`

```
select
item_code,
sum(qty) as  total_qty
from table_name
where 
log_date = '09/12/14'
group by item_code
```

Comment: count() only counts the records. I also want total quantity for each item_code.

Comment: Provide some sample data and expected output from that.